# How to make the other line move forward in the dynamic graph?

Tags: javascript, html, graph

below is the link to code regarding to dynamic graph. I am having a problem of making the red line, being updated and move forward together with the blue line.. I don't know where the problem is that make the red line static in the dynamic graph..

And solution to the code? Thanks again for helping..

http://jsfiddle.net/EkkBQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it to also update the second series of data. I couldn't figure out the smoothing or if it's possible to smooth once you have > 1 data stream.

http://jsfiddle.net/EkkBQ/8/

Key code added:

```
var seriesA = this.series[1];

   setInterval(function() {

   var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time

   y = Math.random();

   seriesA.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

}, 1000);
```

I duplicated the call where the series data is added to the chart - changed the series variable to seriesA and then told it to pull the second series of data (series[1](http://jsfiddle.net/EkkBQ/8/)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it helps! thank you! Never mind about the smoothing, i will figure it out.. Thanks again!

Comment: hey matthew, i have another question here.. How can i display the output of latest data on at the bottom of the graph, instead of user having to mouse over the graph to see the output data... 

http://jsfiddle.net/EkkBQ/16/

Comment: Using the setup you have here, I'm not sure how do to that in a simple way. You're dynamically creating the data so in JS so you'd have to create a new array and send that back out for display. I'm thinking scoping of variables might be a problem. Another problem is that you're creating an infinite amount of data and that will cause you an infinite loop problem and you're page will just keep scrolling with data. I'm not sure you'd want to display the output on a dynamic graph like this without some limits.